# HDFS: How to free space/rebalance after adding new node?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, diskspace

I added a second node to my HDFS. The master server has a disk usage of 91% before adding the node. Afterwards the free space is still getting smaller. I rebalanced the cluster with a threshold of 10 and the block replication factor is set to 3. My Hadoop version is 2.2.4.2-2. Any ideas to free up space on my master node?

Comment: What is your 'master server'? HDFS has namenode and datanodes. No 'master'.

Comment: My 'master server' contains the namenode and one datanode. The second server is the second datanode.

Comment: So you have replication factor 3 on a 2 datanode cluster?

Comment: Correct! I use the default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had one single datanode, presumably holding all HDFS blocks. Each block had only one copy. If you add a second node and keep replication factor 3, then you will at best copy each block to the new node, to obtain an actual replication factor 2 (each block has 2 copies, one on each node). No space reduction on the former single node. If you then add a third datanode you will achieve, at best, 3 copies for each block, one on each node, an no reduction of space on the original node. Only when you add a 4th node can some disk usage reduction be achieved, by migrating about 1/4th of the block replicas off the original node.

You either have to reduce your replication factor, or add more than 3 nodes. 6 nodes will achieve 50% reduction at replication factor 3. Or change the replication factor to 1 and achieve 50% reduction with only 2 nodes, at the risk of loosing blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If i decrease the block replication factor to 2, each datanode have a copy of each block and achieve 33% reduction, right?

Comment: only if you add 3 nodes. Replication factor 2 on two nodes must place 100% of blocks on each node.

Comment: Just to be sure. A replication factor higher than the numbers of datanodes will be ignored and each datanode contains just one copy of a block? I'm a bit confused, cause the size of the data folder of node 1 is 1,7TB and node 2 has a size of 1,2 TB.

Comment: Your namenode log is probably full of replication factor warnings. Your current factor is not ignored. The namenode tries to satisfy it, but it can't. Replicas must be placed on different modes.

Comment: 1.7 vs 1.2 can be from incomplete balancing, from files with replication factor 1 (it can be overwritten for each file). Also make sure you don't count the namenode files too.

Comment: A good read: [Replica placement](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#Replica+Placement%3A+The+First+Baby+Steps)